# When Al Pacino said "Can I get a little hi-de-hi here?" when he sang Sea Of Love, what does "hi-de-hi" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, sea-of-love

In Sea Of Love, Al Pacino said "Can I get a little hi-de-hi here?" when he sang Sea Of Love, what's hi-de-hi mean?

It can be viewed in the movie's script, [here](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Sea_of_Love.pdf) (bottom of page 51)

Comment: When, specifically? Can you describe the scene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe he was asking for some confirmation that what he was saying was coming in loud and clear on the other end.  He was wearing a wire designed to transmit his conversation to detectives who were listening in, and if the wire disengaged then wearing it was moot.

Comment: Your answer is spot on here. There were a male and female undercover detectives also in the restaurant at a table nearby, dressed as a pair of yuppies. They were both wearing 'hearing aids,' which were actually being fed from the surveilance van outside. They could (were supposed to) listen in on Franks conversations with each 'date'/suspect.